# How to translate a whole paragraph with Google Translate

Tags: google-translate

When I paste one sentence in the left field of Google Translate it gets translated. However, if I paste a whole paragraph nothing gets translated and the right field doesn't change at all. Is there a way to make it translate more than one sentence at once? Does it depend on the language? I am translating Bulgarian to English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit the [Translate] button above the "right window". ;)

[image: Translate button on Google Translate - above right text box]

When you paste (or edit) a larger block of text Google does not seem to translate it instantly (on-the-fly), but instead waits until you have entered all the text you want translated. So you need to manually hit the [Translate] button. Probably because translation is computationally expensive. Although it is a bit misleading that a link at the bottom of the page still states "Turn off instant translation" in this case, implying that "instant translation" is active. Toggling this option does not seem to make a difference with large blocks of text.

Comment: Now I am embarrassed for asking this :) But tech does seem to spoil us with time...

Comment: Ha, well, like you say we do get used to things "just happening", like not having to hit the [Save] button etc. It's also a bit misleading that there is still a link at the bottom of the page to "Turn off instant translation", implying that it is still active.

Comment: I did just check to see if there was a keyboard shortcut, but couldn't find one... https://support.google.com/translate/toolkit/answer/147834?hl=en